# JS this.randomrumber = rand returns 'undefined'. Random Number of specified Digits

Tags: javascript, math

pardon me for putting up another question on random number generation. I have a working solution as [*function random_X_digits(digits)*].

But in [***function randnum3(digits)***], I failed to understand why it loses rand (value) after recursive iteration it goes under if 'rand' < minimum xxxx digit number.
looking forward for some simple explanations. Thanks.

[image]

```js
function random_X_digits(digits) {
  let a = 10 ** (digits - 1);
  let b = Math.random();
  return Math.floor(a + b * 9 * a);
}
const n1 = random_X_digits(4); // XXXX digit random number
console.log("n1: " + n1);

function randnum2(digits) {
  let rand = parseInt(10 ** digits * Math.random());
  console.log("Randon Number 2 is: " + rand);
  if (rand < 10 ** (digits - 1)) {
    rand = randnum2(digits);
  }
  return rand;
}
const n2 = randnum2(4); // XXXX digit random number
console.log("n2: " + n2);

function randnum3(digits) {
  let rand = parseInt(10 ** digits * Math.random());
  console.log("Randon Number 3 is: " + rand);
  if (rand < 10 ** (digits - 1)) {
    rand = randnum3(digits); //! this is returning Undefined output. ???
  }
  this.rn = rand;
}
const nrn = new randnum3(4); // XXXX digit random number
const n3 = nrn.rn; //
console.log("n3: " + n3);
```

Answer (score 0):

When a function doesn't have an explicit return statement, it returns undefined.

Your code works fine until `rand` is greater than `10** (digits-1)`. At that point it doesn't return `rand`, but sets a property in the `randnum3` function. If you console.log `randnum3` you will see that property.

```
console.log("n3: " + randnum3.rn);
```

So, a function that doesn't return explicitly, returns undefined. Fix the return statement (like in randnum2) and it will work properly.

Comment: Thanks @Jonatan . In `function randnum3` added `return this.rn = rand;` and got the results as expected
`Randon Number 3 is: 207`
`Randon Number 3 is: 1733`
`n3: 1733`
But I still dont understand, without `return` statement and `if` = `False` , it works fine. but when `if` = `True`  gives `undefined`.

Comment: When you do `return this.rn = rand;`You are a) Giving back the value
b) Setting a property `rn` to the function with the same value (functions are objects). Regarding the flow, I didn't understand your question. I recommend you try to use the debugger. Using the debugger you will be able to set breakpoints (stop the runtime) at any line you want and inspect each value you have. That will help you

Comment: If my response helped, I would appreciate you marking it as the solution or upvoting it :)